# How to write a script that takes in certain user input and appends other options onto it?

Tags: reactjs, bash, scripting

I'm very new to scripting and feel this should be an easy solution. I have the following command:

```
format extract 'src/**/*.ts*' --out-file lang/en.json --id-interpolation-pattern '[sha512:contenthash:base64:6]'
```

Right now, in our package.json, it's just this:

```
  "scripts": {
    "extract": "formatjs extract",
```

What I want a user to be able to run from the command line is something along the lines of:

```
yarn extract 'src/**/*.tsx' --out-file lang/en.json
```

with the remaining `--id-interpolation-pattern '[sha512:contenthash:base64:6]'`
being appended automatically to the end. I'm sure it's probably pretty easy, but how can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Solution was much easier than I thought. This works:

```
echo "Type the path to the directory / file you wish to extract from: "
read extractionFile
echo "Type the path where the extracted json will be output: "
read outputFile
formatjs extract $extractionFile --out-file "$outputFile/lang/en-US.json" --id-interpolation-pattern '[sha512:contenthash:base64:6]'
```